# get search result from website and parse it into android application using KSOAP2

Tags: android, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I am new to android. I have to query a search from my android application on yahoo.com and show results into the app. I prefer to use KSOAP2. Plz let me know the procedure to proceed with some code as well. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for some of the examples try this **[Site](http://javatutorialspoint.blogspot.in/2012/02/android-web-service-access-using-ksoap2.html) & [Site](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.in/2010/11/basic-ksoap-android-tutorial.html) & [Site](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-ksoap2-android-and-parsing-output-data)**. Here you ll get it, how to use **ksoap2** in your android app.